# PowersRepresentations Algorithm

Tags: implementation-details, number-theory

I'm trying to understand the mathematics behind counting the number of representations of a positive integer by $n$ distinct $k$th powers, i.e. I would really like to know how to do the Mathematica function PowersRepresentations by hand. Any explanations, references, even special cases (I'm particularly interested in $k=2$) would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-21.1.160) and [this](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2317482)? For the sum of squares case, see [this](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/4SQUARES.HTM).

Comment: I feel like this is more a mathematics question, than it is a Mathematica one. Or do you specifically want to know how Mathematica is calculating power represantations?